# Como clicar no ok dos alert do java script via WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, navegador-de-internet

Como posso desativar todos os alertas de javascript via web browser ?

Quando estou carregando a pagina.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
alert('Olá, bem vindo ao ultimo passo');
function nextStep()
{
    setTimeout(function () {
       window.location.href = "entrada.php"; //will redirect to your blog page (an ex: blog.php)
    }, 2000);
}
</script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="alert('Mas não tanto ao ponto de o botão de Finalizar tarefas não funcionar');alert('Boa sorte ;-)');">
<h1>5 - Injeção de JavaScript</h1>
<h2>Objetivo</h2>
<p>Essa página, como você deve ter percebido tem uma sequencia de Alerts, 
o que necessitamos é que você clique em "OK" nos Alerts ou de um jeito 
para que eles não aparecam mais</p>

                <p style="width:500px;text-align:right;">
                    <input type="submit" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Finalizar Tarefas" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="nextStep();">
                </p>
                <script>
                alert('A Tarefa aqui consiste em barrar o Javascript');

                </script>
</body></html>
```

Ela de cara já amostra o alert.

```
alert('Olá, bem vindo ao ultimo passo');
```

Tentei fazer da forma abaixo, mas não estou conseguindo.

```
webBrowser.Navigate(url);
while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete && webBrowser.Document == null)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
}

var doc = webBrowser.Document.Window.Open(url, "", "", true);

HtmlElement head = doc.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptEl = doc.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
string alertBlocker = "window.alert = function () { }";
element.text = alertBlocker;
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
head.InvokeMember("click");


Thread.Sleep(2000);

HtmlElement submit = doc.Document.GetElementById("submit");
submit.InvokeMember("click");
```

O que preciso é clicar em "OK" nos Alerts ou de um jeito para que eles não apareçam mais.

Comment: Qual o contexto desses 'steps' ? Pois depende do contexto para aplicação, de modo simples podes definir uma sessão ou cookie informando que os alerts ja foram vistos e usar um if para saber se precisam ou não serem exibidos de novo.

Comment: @AnthraxisBR, não entendi... o que você esta falando sobre contexto ...

Comment: Contexto é o que esses alerts são, se eles são mesmo para interação com usuário, ou se eles são apenas informações da construção da página, mas acho que em qualquer caso gravar que eles ja foram vistos em um cookie ou em uma sessão ja vai resolver.

Comment: são de interação de usuário, eles são carregados assim que a página é aberta no browser.

Comment: if(localStorage.getItem('alert1') === '1'){
  //nada
}else{
 alert('Olá, bem vindo ao ultimo passo');
  localStorage.setItem('alert1','1'); 
}.
Se você iniciar uma sesssão para o alert, salvar um valor e comparar na sessão se ele existe, ele só vai ser exibido de novo no fim da sessão, veja ese trecho que eu coloquei aqui, substitui o código do primeiro alert por ele, se for isso mesmo preparo uma resposta decente.

Comment: a mensagem é mostrada pelo navegador...e não na página, você vai precisar de utilizar função do sistema operacional para buscar a mensagem e clicar no botão. Já fiz isso e tenho o código, chegando em casa publico aqui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou colocar como outra resposta, pois se trata de uma solução diferente proposta na primeira.

Dessa forma, você pode não clicar nas caixas, mas impedir que elas apareçam:

Foi preciso adicionar a referência COM para `Microsoft HTML Object Library`, e utilizar o namespace `mshtml`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código ficou assim:

```
using mshtml;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BlockJS
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            webBrowser1.Navigate("[url]");
        }

        private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {
            InjectAlertBlocker();
        }

        private void InjectAlertBlocker()
        {
            HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
            IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
            string alertBlocker = "window.alert = function () { }";
            element.text = alertBlocker;
            head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
        }

    }
}
```

Colocando no seu código, do `Stap6();` deveria ficar algo assim:

```
    public void Stap6()
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://indigo.rafson.com.br/05.php");
        webBrowser1.Navigated += (s, e) => {

            HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
            IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
            string alertBlocker = "window.alert = function () { }";
            element.text = alertBlocker;
            head.AppendChild(scriptEl);

        };

        NextStap = StapFinalize;
    }
```

Comment: cara não rolou.. não sei o que fiz de errado.

Comment: mostre seu código

Comment: https://github.com/MarconcilioSouza/stackoverflow/blob/master/WebBrowser_Indigo/WebBrowser_Indigo/Form1.cs

Comment: o  Stap6() é o que estou tentando fazer

Comment: você não colocou o código ...

Comment: consegui resolver, tive que aplicar as duas respostas para resolver o problema.

Answer (score 2):

como comentei, a mensagem é exibida pelo navegador, e você não conseguirá acessar ela pelo html do documento. Você precisa utilizar funções do sistema operacional para interagir com as mensagens:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter,        string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string        lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam,        IntPtr lParam);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void SwitchToThisWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool fAltTab);


    public static void ClickOKButton()
    {
        IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow("#32770", "Mensagem da página da web");
        SwitchToThisWindow(hwnd, false);
        hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "OK");
        uint message = 0xf5;
        SendMessage(hwnd, message, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

Obs.: A Mensagem de alerta não aparece logo após a página ser carregada, há um tempo de delay, assim, utilizo um timer para atrasar a execução do método e garantir que ele seja executado quando já houver a mensagem na tela.

Comment: lpClassName Isso não é dinâmico ? FindWindow("#32770"

Comment: Quis dizer IntPtr? O código #32770 não... Pelo que me parece, é a identificação de mensagens... O título da janela, você pode alterar para qual aparece no seu caso, mas acredito que seja igual também

Comment: #32770 identifica caixas de diálogo do  Windows

Comment: as mensagem são mostradas no browser

Comment: As mensagens são mostradas pelo browser... Eu uso esse código aqui, funciona perfeitamente, não conseguiu funcionar?

Comment: não rolou aqui, continuar mostrando

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770522/how-to-handle-message-boxes-while-using-webbrowser-in-c

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67186/discussion-between-rovann-linhalis-and-marconcilio-souza).