# Impedir, confirmar ou dismiss em javascript alerts num objeto webbrowser VB.NET

Tags: .net, winforms, vb.net, navegador-de-internet

Estou enfrentando problemas com alertas javascript no meu webbrowser.
Estou criando uma automação e após dar submit em algumas páginas no webbrowser, surgem alertas javascript com o protocolo gerado pela página, porém com o alerta aberto o webbrowser não carrega outras página via **navigate**, quando o timer envia o comando a aplicação quebra pois está o alerta ativo.

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate(paginaInicial)
```

Já tentei utilizar SendKeys, porém sem sucesso. Em minhas pesquisas não achei nenhuma solução eficaz.

```
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
```

Caríssimos, como eu resolvo esse problema?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como clicar no ok dos alert do java script via WebBrowser?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/246441/como-clicar-no-ok-dos-alert-do-java-script-via-webbrowser)

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/246480/69359

Comment: nos links supracitados, tem as duas formas, bloquear que o alert apareça e clicar no ok das janelas.

Comment: Já havia tentado usar uma solução parecida porém sem sucesso! Essa solução é em C#, não conheço muito  estou tentando escrever isso em VB, mas estou enfrentando dificuldades.

Comment: Já havia tentado também injetar no head, algo do tipo "window.alert = function () { }", mas sem sucesso também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver esse problema da seguinte maneira:
No momento em que preciso levar o browser para a página inicial, 
**WebBrowser1.Navigate(paginaInicial)**, eu fiz o seguinte... Quando tentar ir para a página inicial e o browser estiver travado com o alerta ativo, eu aplico o método **.Dispose()** no objeto, e ainda defino ele como **= nothing**.
Após isso eu crio novamente um WebBrowser como as mesmas características, porém ele terá um nove diferente então usei um **Random()** para gerar um objeto com nome aleatório.
Como minha aplicação só tem um WebBrowser, todos os locais onde eu faço alguma requisição do meu WebBrowser eu preciso utilizar um código que busca o objeto pelo CType(), já que não sei o nome dos novos WebBrowsers que serão criados.
Então o código fica assim:

```
//Tenta redirecionar para página inicial
Try
//Procura o WebBrowser ativo
For Each ctrlsweb In Me.Controls
  If (ctrlsweb.GetType() Is GetType(WebBrowser)) Then
    Dim browserc As WebBrowser = CType(ctrlsweb, WebBrowser)
    //Aqui você executa as ações para esse webbrowser que o codigo transformou em variável
    browserc.Navigate(pagInicial)
  End If
Next

//Se houver algum erro, então e
Catch ex As Exception

//Elimina o objeto Browser ativo 
For Each ctrlsweb In Me.Controls
  If (ctrlsweb.GetType() Is GetType(WebBrowser)) Then
    Dim browserc As WebBrowser = CType(ctrlsweb, WebBrowser)
    browserc.Focus()
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
    browserc.Dispose()
    browserc = Nothing
  End If
Next

//Gera um número randomico para usar no nome do objeto Browser
Dim geraRand As Random = New Random()
Dim numero As String = geraRand.Next(1013, 8939)

//Cria novo WebBrowser
Dim web As New WebBrowser
web.Name = "WebBrowser" & numero
web.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
web.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True

End Try
```

Se seu WebBrowser tiver ações Handler assim como o meu, por exemplo **DocumentCompleted**, **Navigating**, etc... você pode usar após a criação do WebBrowser esse código:

```
AddHandler web.Navigating, Sub()
                             BarStatus.Text = "Carregando..."
                             StatusOK.Visible = True
                             //Mais código aqui...
                           End Sub
```